# MS SQL - How to get list of comma/semi-colon separated list of e-mail addresses searched in from a large string

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, email, search, substring

How to extract the list of all email addresses available in a string, as a comma/semicolon separated list

```
SELECT dbo.getEmailAddresses('this is misc andrew@g.com')

--output andrew@g.com

SELECT dbo.getEmailAddresses('this is misc andrew@g.com and a medium text returning %John@acme.com')
--output andrew@g.com; John@acme.com
```

Comment: Is this part of an import routine? Or business logic? SQL won't be the best tool for this at all...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a UDF for this. Correct this line `SET @MailTempl='[A-Za-z0-9_.-]` if you need additional (for example non-English symbols in an E-mail address). [Here is a full list of allowed characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getEmailAddresses] (@Str varchar(8000))  
RETURNS varchar(8000) AS  
BEGIN 

declare @i int, @StartPos int,@AtPos int,@EndPos int;
declare @MailList varchar(8000);
declare @MailTempl varchar(100);


SET @MailList=NULL;
SET @MailTempl='[A-Za-z0-9_.-]'; --allowing symbols in e-mail not including @

SET @AtPos=PATINDEX('%'+@MailTempl+'@'+@MailTempl+'%',@Str)+1;
While @AtPos>1
begin
  --go left
  SET @i=@AtPos-1;
  while (substring(@Str,@i,1) like @MailTempl) SET @i=@i-1;
  SET @StartPos=@i+1;

  --go right
  SET @i=@AtPos+1;
  while (substring(@Str,@i,1) like @MailTempl) SET @i=@i+1;
  SET @EndPos=@i-1;

  SET @MailList=isnull(@MailList+';','')+Substring(@Str,@StartPos,@EndPos-@StartPos+1);

  --prepare for the next round
  SET @Str=substring(@Str,@EndPos+1,LEn(@Str));
  SET @AtPos=PATINDEX('%'+@MailTempl+'@'+@MailTempl+'%',@Str)+1;

end;

RETURN @MailList;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
create function getEmailAddresses
(
@test varchar(max)
)
returns varchar(max)
As
BEGIN
declare @emaillist varchar(max)
--SET @test=' this is it by it a@b.com dsdkjl dsaldkj a@b.com dasdlk c@bn.com dsafhjkf anand@p.com d fdajf s@s.com .'

;WITH CTE as(
select reverse(left(reverse(left(@test,CHARINDEX('.com',@test)+3)),charindex(' ',reverse(left(@test,CHARINDEX('.com',@test)+3))))) as emailids,
right(@test,len(@test)-(CHARINDEX('.com',@test)+3)) rem
union all
select CASE WHEN len(rem)>2 then reverse(left(reverse(left(rem,CHARINDEX('.com',rem)+3)),charindex(' ',reverse(left(rem,CHARINDEX('.com',rem)+3))))) else 'a' end as emailids ,
CASE WHEN len(rem) > 2 then right(rem,len(rem)-(CHARINDEX('.com',rem)+3)) else 'a' end rem
from CTE where LEN(rem)>2
)
select @emaillist =STUFF((select ','+emailids  from CTE for XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
return @emaillist
END

select dbo.getEmailAddresses('this is it by it a@b.com dsdkjl dsaldkj a@b.com dasdlk c@bn.com dsafhjkf anand@p.com d fdajf s@s.com .')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Declare @str varchar(max) = 'this is misc andrew@g.com and a medium text returning John@acme.com'

    ;With Cte AS(
    SELECT
        Items = Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
    FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    CAST('<X>' + REPLACE(@str,  ' '  , '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Splitdata  

            ) X  

        CROSS APPLY Splitdata.nodes('/X') Split(a) )

SELECT Email = STUFF((
                SELECT ';'+ Items
                FROM Cte
                Where Items
                LIKE '[A-Z0-9]%[@][A-Z]%[.][A-Z]%'
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

*Result*

**EmailAddress**

```
andrew@g.com;John@acme.com
```

N.B.~ You may need to do the following

a) As per your requirement , you need to make a TVF (Table valued function). You can refer the article on [Split Function in Sql Server using Set base approach](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code1797-split-function-in-sql-server-using-set-base-approach.aspx)

b) The Email validation like clause is OK to work with but for more complex requirement you may have to enhance it.

c)If needed, you may have to clean the data before applying the filtration  clause. e.g. %John@acme.com is an invalid email.so remove the "%" sign and then apply the filtering clause.

But as some one mentioned that, it is better not to do the string splitting/ manipulation much in Sql Server side and I agree to his point , so here is a C# code for achieving the same

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "this is misc andrew@g.com and a medium text returning John@acme.com";

            var result = GetValidEmails(str).Aggregate((a,b)=>a+";" + b);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static List<string> GetValidEmails(string input)
        {
            List<string> lstValidEmails = new List<string>();
            string regexPattern = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
            foreach (string email in input.Split(' '))
            {
                if (new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(email))
                {
                    lstValidEmails.Add(email);
                }
            }
            return lstValidEmails;
        }
```

Hope this will be helpful.